# Laravel - validation | The input field should be one of two values

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate a form request and I want to accept the field say `test` if only it has a value or `ABC` or `XYZ`. How can I achieve this?

I currently have

```
$request->validate([
    'test' =>  'required|unique:tests',   
]);
```

Comment: See, there is no need to validation required. You can use like: `if(!empty($request->test) || $request->test == 'ABC' || $request->test == 'XYZ') { Do the things here}` Hope this helps you! Let me know.

Comment: And if you want to use only laravel validation rule, use `regex` like: `$request->validate([
    'test' =>  'required|unique:tests|regex:/ABC|XYZ/g',  
]);` Here `g` is global search , retain the index of last match

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Laravel docs are quite helpful when it comes to these issues.

[Laravel Docs - Validation - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#available-validation-rules)

[Laravel Docs - Validation - Rule - in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in)

```
'test' => [
    'required',
    Rule::in(['ABC', 'XYZ']),
]
```

or

```
'test' => 'required|in:ABC,XYZ',
```

Comment: There was no need for the condescension. You could have just said, "There is a [in] rule which would handle this situation."   The [in] rule is easily overlooked if the programmer is searching for a way to OR rules.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression to validate this field

your regular expression for ABC OR XYZ

Code is

```
 $request->validate([
    'test' =>  'required|unique:tests|regex:/ABC|XYZ/g',   
]);
```