# Laravel - Validate Nullable Fields Where Field Input Should Be One Of A Given Set Of Values

Tags: php, laravel

I have two checkbox fields `tech` and `active` that I want to be `nullable` but I also want the values that can be entered to be restricted to a single value for one field and one of two values for the other field.

I came across the answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448254/laravel-validation-the-input-field-should-be-one-of-two-values) but I don't seem to implement it properly. Heres my code:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:150',
    'email' => 'required|string|max:200',
    'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
    'branch' => 'required|string',
    'department' => 'required|string',
    'tech' => ['nullable','digits:1', Rule::in([1, 2])],
    'role' => 'required|string',
    'active' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:6', Rule::in(['active'])]
 ]);
```

If I do this:

```
'tech' => 'nullable|digits:1',
'active' => 'nullable|string|max:6'
```

It works, but I need to validate the values that these fields can allow.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: i have editted it @ChinLeung

Comment: Can you show how you are sending the data/request to the server? I have tried a simple request with `'tech' => 'nullable|digits:1|in:1,2', 'active' => 'nullable|string|max:6|in:active'` and it is working just fine.

Comment: oh okay i'm using ```['nullable', 'string', 'max:6', Rule::in(['active'])]``` instead. Let me implement yours

Comment: I don't think it's related to the validation rule as it works fine the way you have it too. I think it's in the data that you are sending that is wrong. Can you show me what the output of `dd($request->all())` gives you? Or maybe `dd($request->tech)`.

Comment: take for example my active field with this in place ```nullable|string|max:6|in:active``` before submit i ```inspect from chrome``` and i manually change the value from ```active``` to ```actives``` it still submits my form and that's wrong behaviour because i set ```max:6```

Comment: Open your chrome in the network tab, and look at the `Request Payload` under the `Network` tab to see the sent data. Otherwise, as I've mentioned, simply do a `dd($request->all());` to see the actual data received by the server.

Comment: It's hard for me to help you if you can't show me the code to send the data, or the output of the `dd`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working now. I tested  using the ```tech``` field now and it worked fine. So i double checked and my ```active``` field is meant to be ```activate``` actually. So this ```in:active``` works for me now rather than this ```Rule::in(['active'])```

Comment: maybe you could upload your answer and i'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chin Leung's implementation via the comments section solved the problem for me.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'name' => 'required|string|max:150',
   'email' => 'required|string|max:200',
   'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
   'branch' => 'required|string',
   'department' => 'required|string',
   'tech' => 'nullable|digits:1|in:1,2',
   'role' => 'required|string',
   'activate' => 'nullable|string|max:6|in:active'
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass closures to validators, even in the validator class.

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|string|max:150',
    'email' => 'required|string|max:200',
    'phone' => 'required|digits:11',
    'branch' => 'required|string',
    'department' => 'required|string',
    'tech' => function($attribute, $value, $fail){
        if (isset($value)) {
            sizeof($value) > 1 ?? return $fail($attribute." is invalid");
            in_array($value, [1,2]) ?? return $fail($attribute." is invalid");
        }
    },
    'role' => 'required|string',
    'active' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:6', Rule::in(['active'])]
 ]);
```